# RViz ignores COLLADA mesh colours

Tags: ros, collada, markers.rviz, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a COLLADA (.dae) file that I have exported from blender. Its just a cube that has been shaded green.

However, whenever I try to get rviz to display this mesh (using a Marker display) all I get is a white cube.

I have set the marker colours to RGBA = {0, 0, 0, 0} in the message. I have set /mesh_use_embedded_materials to true. I read somewhere that if there is an ambient colour in the mesh file with one of its components set to 0 that rviz wont render it properly, I checked that and there were no zeros.

[This link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/y2lbr0cn5ul8jy0/AAD24vtkl2DpPrt-KOsFO740a?dl=0) has the mesh file and screenshots from blender and rviz.

Can someone tell me how to get rviz to render my mesh using the coulours specified in the mesh file?

I am using the lastest version of Blender (2.72, downloaded just the other day). I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo 1.11.9

Bidski

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198860/rviz-ignores-collada-mesh-colours/) by [Bidski](https://answers.ros.org/users/20952/bidski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2014-12-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Blender export materials with a null ambient lightning, this is probably why your meshes don't look like expected.

### Manually

I do not know what to change in the Blender material to set the ambient so I manually edit the exported `dae` files; Replace

```
<ambient>
  <color sid="ambient">0 0 0 1</color>
</ambient>
```

with

```
<ambient>
  <color sid="ambient">0.1 0.1 0.1 1</color>
</ambient>
```

### Python script

Here is a script that copies the diffuse color to the ambient color, first edit a new script file (this is for Nemo, not Nautilus):

```
gedit ~/.local/share/nemo/scripts/RViz\ collada
```

Use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if xml-twig-tools is installed
pkg_ok=$(dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Status}\n' xml-twig-tools|grep "install ok installed")
if [ "" == "$pkg_ok" ]; then
    notify-send "Missing package" -t 1 "Please install xml-twig-tools"
    exit 0
fi

count=0

# Reads Nautilus / nemo arguments to detect which file have to processed
# Processes only selected files with .dae extension (case insensitive)
for file in $(find ${NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS} -iname '*.dae'); do
    # Fetches all "diffuse" properties from materials accross the file into a single string
    diffuse_properties=`xml_grep 'diffuse' $file --text_only`

    # Splits diffuse_properties string into an array of strings
    readarray -t properties_array <<<"$diffuse_properties"

    # Replaces only the first occurence in the file each time
    for element in "${properties_array[@]}"
    do
        sed -i "0,/ambient\">0\ 0\ 0\ 1/s//ambient\">$element/" $file
    done

    ((count++))
done

# Notify user
notify-send "RViz collada" -t 1 "$count files tweaked"
exit 0
```

Make the script executable:

```
chmod +x ~/.local/share/nemo/scripts/*
```

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2015-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-06**:
See also [rviz/issues/836](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/836).